# How to Reuse Database Connection under Python CGI?

Tags: python, cgi

I'm new to python and mysql-python module. Is there any way to reuse db connection so that we may not connect() and close() every time a request comes.

More generally, how can I keep 'status' on server-side? Can somebody give me a tutorial to follow or guide me somehow, lots of thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not possible with **CGI**, the original Common Gateway Interface dictates that the program be run from scratch for each request.

You'd want to use WSGI instead (a Python standard), which allows your application be long-lived. WSGI in turn is easiest if you use a Web Framework such as Pyramid, Flask or Django; their integrations with databases like MySQL support *connection pooling* out of box.